# How to do UI test with airbnb epoxy?

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, gui-testing, epoxy

Currently I'm working in a project that's using epoxy and I'm having a hard time thinking on how could I create UI/integration tests with it. At Epoxy github's repository I've only got a hint about testing the RecyclerView but I don't think this is the best way.

Could you give me any tips?

Thanks :)